# resize image in android drawable

Tags: android, drawable, image-resizing

I have full resolution images in **drawable folder** need to **resize** according to **phone screen size** how to do that ?

Comment: This should be for what you looking; http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score -1):

to get the width you should do this :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
double deviceWidth;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
            deviceWidth= display.getWidth();
        else {
            display.getSize(size);
            deviceWidth=size.x;
        }
```