# What is the best practice for providing resources for an Android AnimationDrawable PNG sequence?

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen, animationdrawable

I have created a sequence of PNG's for a splash loader animation in the various screen densities. I am using AnimationDrawable and have created the animation in an XML file. The sequence of PNG's for each density is 30 frames long. At 5 densities and 220kb per sequence, my res folder is starting to get too large.

Is there a more efficient way of providing resources for this PNG sequence without compressing the PNG's? If I provide just the xxhdpi size will it scale these PNG's down for smaller screens? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend only using one folder using your `xxhdpi` so it is compatible with higher and lower density, and dont just let android re-size it for you, you need to at least re-size your image programatically.

You can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684947/resize-image-in-android-drawable) on how to resize image while maintining its aspect ratio programatically.